# Showing ProgressDialog OnItemClick

Tags: java, android, progressdialog

I've a ListView with a list of item retrieving with JSON and i want to show a ProgressDialog on item click.

```
listNews.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position,
                    long arg3) {
                ProgressDialog dialog;
                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(v.getContext(), "Please wait..", "Loading data", true);
                dialog.setCancelable(false);
                dialog.show();
                News n = (News)listNews.getItemAtPosition(position);

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), SingleActivity.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("actu_id", n.ID);
                dialog.dismiss();
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);


            }

        });
```

ProgressDialog not showing...
Same problem when I define this progressDialog in OnCreate in SingleActivity.class

Can you help me ?

Sorry for my english ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a problem related with your workflow. Since you're doing additional tasks on the UI thread, the ProgressDialog doesn't get to be shown.

You should either spawn a thread for doing the extra work, then dismiss your dialog and launch your new Intent with runOnUiThread() or with a Handler.

Although, the best option would be using AsyncTask, showing your ProgressDialog onPreExecute(), doing your work in doInBackground() and then dismissing it onPostExecute() and launching your new activity.

Answer (score 4):

I think it is because you are dismissing it right away